# Remove a behavior for a specific body after being added into the world

Tags: physicsjs

Is it possible to remove a Behavior for a specific Body after already being added it to the world? For example, you have a tank which has been suffered gravity, collision behaviors..., then you kill it by colliding the rocket with the tank, then you still want to keep the body of the tank in the world but won't be able to collide again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want to implement this but yes. The easiest way would be to use the `.applyTo` method on the collision detection behavior.

```
var collidingBodies = [];
collidingBodies.push( tank ); // could add more too...

var collisionDetection = Physics.behavior('body-collision-detection');
collisionDetection.applyTo( collidingBodies );
world.add( collisionDetection );

// elsewhere... 
// when explosion happens
var idx = collidingBodies.indexOf( tank );
if ( idx > -1 ){
    collidingBodies.slice( idx, 1 );
    collisionDetection.applyTo( collidingBodies );
}
```

The collision detection is applied to a set of objects (in an array). When the tank explodes, remove it from the array and pass that array back to `.applyTo` to update the behavior.

You can also use the [Query functionality](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/docs/#Physics-query) to help organize the arrays better but that's the general idea.